# GStreamer linking error

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm trying to build the source code of https://github.com/iiordanov/remote-desktop-clients/tree/master/eclipse_projects/Opaque.

Now there's an error while building the gstreamer library:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing 'D:\Entwicklung\Android\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Entwicklung\Android-Projekte\app\Spice-Client\app\jni\src\Android.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Entwicklung\Android-Projekte\app\Spice-Client\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib gst-build-mips64/libgstreamer_android.so}
Android NDK: WARNING:D:\Entwicklung\Android-Projekte\app\Spice-Client\app\jni\src\Android.mk:spice: non-system libraries in linker flags: D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libssl.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libcrypto.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libcelt051.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libgovirt.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/librest-0.7.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libjpeg.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libusb.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libusbredirhost.a D:/Entwicklung/Android-Projekte/app/Spice-Client/app/jni/src/../libs/deps/lib/libusbredirparser.a    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-mips64/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-mips64/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-mips64/libgstreamer_android.so
clang.exe: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=gold'
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_mips64] Error 1
```

I also tried to rename the linker to "gold.exe", but it doesn't change anything
I'm currently using the ARM Build of GStreamer Version 1.9.2 
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.9.2/

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi

SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS   := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/deps

GSTREAMER_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/gstreamer
CROSS_DIR  := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/gstreamer
spice_objs := \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libssl.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcrypto.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcelt051.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libgovirt.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/librest-0.7.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libjpeg.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libusb.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libusbredirhost.a \
    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libusbredirparser.a


LOCAL_MODULE    := spice

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gtk/spice-uri.c gtk/channel-record.c gtk/channel-playback.c gtk/channel-cursor.c \
                   gtk/channel-webdav.c gtk/spice-cmdline.c gtk/coroutine_gthread.c gtk/spice-util.c \
                   gtk/spice-session.c gtk/spice-channel.c gtk/spice-marshal.c gtk/spice-glib-enums.c \
                   gtk/gio-coroutine.c gtk/channel-base.c gtk/channel-main.c gtk/spice-proxy.c gtk/bio-gsocket.c \
                   gtk/glib-compat.c gtk/channel-display.c gtk/channel-display-mjpeg.c gtk/channel-inputs.c \
                   gtk/decode-glz.c gtk/decode-jpeg.c gtk/decode-zlib.c gtk/wocky-http-proxy.c gtk/channel-port.c \
                   gtk/spice-client.c gtk/spice-audio.c gtk/spice-gstaudio.c gtk/vmcstream.c \
                   gtk/channel-usbredir.c gtk/usb-device-manager.c gtk/usbutil.c gtk/bio-gio.c \
                   spice-common/common/generated_client_demarshallers.c spice-common/common/generated_client_demarshallers1.c \
                   spice-common/common/generated_client_marshallers.c spice-common/common/generated_client_marshallers1.c \
                   spice-common/common/mem.c spice-common/common/marshaller.c spice-common/common/canvas_utils.c \
                   spice-common/common/backtrace.c spice-common/common/sw_canvas.c spice-common/common/pixman_utils.c \
                   spice-common/common/lines.c spice-common/common/rop3.c spice-common/common/quic.c spice-common/common/lz.c \
                   spice-common/common/region.c spice-common/common/ssl_verify.c spice-common/common/log.c \
                   spice-common/common/snd_codec.c \
                   virt-viewer/virt-viewer-file.c virt-viewer/virt-viewer-util.c \
                   android/android-service.c android/android-spicy.c android/android-spice-widget.c \
                   android/android-io.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += $(spice_objs) \
                   -ljnigraphics -llog -ldl -lstdc++ -lz \
                   -malign-double -malign-loops

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GSpice\" \
                   -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE \
                   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -UHAVE_SYS_SHM_H -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE  \
                   -D_REENTRANT -DWITH_GSTAUDIO

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/gtk \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/spice-common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/spice-common/common \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/spice-common/spice-protocol \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/virt-viewer \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/govirt-1.0 \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/rest-0.7 \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/jpeg-turbo \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/libusb \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/usbredirparser \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include/usbredirhost \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/include \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/include/glib-2.0 \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/include/libxml2 \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/include/pixman-1 \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/include/spice-1 \
                    $(CROSS_DIR)/lib/glib-2.0/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS    :=  $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS) \
                   -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wl,--no-undefined \
                   -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_LDLIBS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/gstreamer
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
G_IO_MODULES              := gnutls
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := pixman-1 gstreamer-app-1.0 libsoup-2.4 libxml-2.0 gthread-2.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 gio-unix-2.0

TARGET_LDFLAGS := -z muldefs

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

So does anybody know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like gstreamer unconditionally passes `-fuse-ld=gold`:

```
$ grep -rI fuse-ld .
...
./share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer-1.0.mk:GSTREAMER_LD                  := -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-soname,lib$(GSTREAMER_ANDROID_MODULE_NAME).so
```

The NDK doesn't ship ld.gold for mips/mips64. You need to gate `-fuse-ld=gold` use against `TARGET_ARCH` like so:

```
# mips/mips64 don't have ld.gold.
ifeq (,$(filter mips mips64,$(TARGET_ARCH)))
    LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fuse-ld=gold
endif
```

Alternatively, just don't pass `-fuse-ld=gold`. The NDK will default to it for the other architectures (aside from aarch64, where bfd is still the default).

Answer (score 0):

Precompiled gstreamer binaries does not include mips support yet. You should exclude mips from build..